# dicom file read error: 'RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration'

Tags: python-3.x, pydicom

below is the python code

```
def load_scan(path):
print(path)
slices = [dicom.read_file(path + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(path)]
slices.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.InstanceNumber))
try:
    slice_thickness = np.abs(slices[0].ImagePositionPatient[2] - slices[1].ImagePositionPatient[2])
except:
    slice_thickness = np.abs(slices[0].SliceLocation - slices[1].SliceLocation)

for s in slices:
    s.SliceThickness = slice_thickness

return slices


patient = load_scan(filepath)
```

i downloaded the sample dicom files from [link](https://wiki.cancerimagingarchive.net/display/Public/LIDC-IDRI)

any help would be great... how to read dicom files and then process them.

Comment: This is a python 3.7 error, probably `dicom` does not yet support 3.7

Answer (score 1):

Find where filereader.py is. You can see the directory from the traceback itself.

Replace `raise StopIteration` with `return` and you are set to go.

Your filereader.py directory will look like this : `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dicom/filereader.py`

Answer (score 0):

I believe dicom is no longer supported,  Use [pydicom](https://pypi.org/project/pydicom/) instead of dicom.